# Pega o maior valor dentro do select do linq

Tags: c#, linq, webforms, linq-to-entities

Existe alguma forma que dentro do `select do linq` eu possa pegar o maior valor de um campo do tipo `decimal?`, conforme o código abaixo?

```
MaxValor = Math.Max(CF.Janeiro, CF.Fevereiro, CF.Marco, CF.Abril, CF.Maio, CF.Junho, CF.Julho, CF.Agosto, CF.Setembro, CF.Novembro, CF.Dezembro),



 CamposFormImport = CForm
 .Select(CF => new VwCamposFormulario
 {
     IdCampoModelo = CF.IdCampoModelo,
     Janeiro = (CF.Janeiro + (CF.Janeiro * Porcentagem)),
     Fevereiro = (CF.Fevereiro + (CF.Fevereiro * Porcentagem)),
     Marco = (CF.Marco + (CF.Marco * Porcentagem)),
     Abril = (CF.Abril + (CF.Abril * Porcentagem)),
     Maio = (CF.Maio + (CF.Maio * Porcentagem)),
     Junho = (CF.Junho + (CF.Junho * Porcentagem)),
     Julho = (CF.Julho + (CF.Julho * Porcentagem)),
     Agosto = (CF.Agosto + (CF.Agosto * Porcentagem)),
     Setembro = (CF.Setembro + (CF.Setembro * Porcentagem)),
     Outubro = (CF.Outubro + (CF.Outubro * Porcentagem)),
     Novembro = (CF.Novembro + (CF.Novembro * Porcentagem)),
     Dezembro = (CF.Dezembro + (CF.Dezembro * Porcentagem)),
     Media = CF.Total != 00M ? ((CF.Total / 12) + ((CF.Total / 12) * Porcentagem)) : 0,
     MaxValor = Math.Max(CF.Janeiro, CF.Fevereiro, CF.Marco, CF.Abril, CF.Maio, CF.Junho, CF.Julho, CF.Agosto, CF.Setembro, CF.Novembro, CF.Dezembro),
 })
 .ToList();
```

Pelo que pude ver o método `Max` só tem suporte para dois parâmetros, nesse caso também não posso usar o método `GroupBy do linq.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar várias chamadas do `Math.Max` para resolver isso:

```
MaxValor = Math.Max(CF.Janeiro, Math.Max(CF.Fevereiro, ..., Math.Max(CF.Novembro, CF.Dezembro)...))
```

Ou usar um método adicional que faça isso para você:

```
static decimal MaxExtended(params decimal[] args)
{
    return args.Aggregate(0m, (d1, d2) => Math.Max(d1, d2));
}
```

E usá-lo na expressão do Select:

```
MaxValor = MaxExtended(CF.Janeiro, CF.Fevereiro, ..., CF.Dezembro)
```

Comment: Gostei do método por ser mais limpo. vlw